# VB.NET how to update Gantt Chart values display of an MSProject

Tags: vb.net, project, ms-project, gantt-chart

I'am working on a MSProject standard 2019 in VB.NET. I didn't find the solution yet on the web so here I come. I need to reorder the tasks of a project displayed on the gantt chart. I have previously reordered my list of tasks contained in the Project but I can not update this same gantt chart after modification. I work on a script already started but I do not understand how to interact with the gantt chart of the MSProject from my Project in order to update it. Here some description of what I want to do and then the Module which was given to me.

[Here the function which change the task order in my project and my attempt to update the gantt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHG66.png)

[The purpose is to reorder tasks here, for exemple to switch rows 6 and 9...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ANUJ.png)

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject

Module WbsImportationManager

''' <summary>
''' This function manage the importation form a WBS dictionary into a blank MS project
''' </summary>
''' <param name="pathToSavaProject"> path to save the new project filled</param>
''' <param name="pathToMasterProject"> path to the master to link the resources with it </param>
''' <param name="Projects"> Project object that represent all projects data</param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Sub CreateProjectFromWBS(pathToMasterProject As String, ByRef ProjectApp As MSProject.Application, ByRef WBSDictionaryApp As Excel.Application, ByVal enableMaster As Boolean, pathToSaveProject As String)

    Dim Projects As New WBSProjects
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim errorDetected As New List(Of Integer())






    Call GlobalApplication.Application.UpdatePercentLoadForm(1)


    Call Projects.ImportProjectFromWbsDictionary(WBSDictionaryApp, enableMaster:=enableMaster)

    lastrow = Projects.GetProject.NumberOfTask
    For line = 0 To lastrow - 1

        OrthographeVerification(WBSDictionaryApp, line, Projects.GetProject)
    Next

    Call ResetAllGreyColumn(WBSDictionaryApp, Projects.GetProject)

    ProjectApp.ActiveProject.Name = Projects.GetProject.ProjectName

    Call GlobalApplication.Application.UpdatePercentLoadForm(10)

    Dim ErrorCode = Projects.GetProject.CheckWbsData(errorDetected)

    If (ErrorCode) Then
        Call ErrorInData(WBSDictionaryApp, errorDetected, Projects.GetProject)

        Throw New System.Exception("Eror in WBS Dictionary")
    Else

        Call GlobalApplication.Application.UpdatePercentLoadForm(30)
        Projects.GetProject.ExportToMS(ProjectApp.Projects(1))

        Call GlobalApplication.Application.UpdatePercentLoadForm(40)
        If (enableMaster) Then
            Call CreateResources(pathToMasterProject, ProjectApp)
        End If
        Call GlobalApplication.Application.UpdatePercentLoadForm(40)

        Call GenerateIndentation(Projects.GetProject, ProjectApp)

        'to import calendar from master (country problem)

        Call GlobalApplication.Application.UpdatePercentLoadForm(50)

        Call ProjectApp.CalculateProject()

        Call ProjectApp.FileSaveAs(pathToSaveProject + "\" + Projects.GetProject().ProjectName)

        If (enableMaster) Then
            Call AddSubProjectIntoMaster(ProjectApp, pathToSaveProject, Projects.GetProject())
        End If
        Call ProjectApp.FileSave()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub OrthographeVerification(ByRef WBSDictionaryApp As Excel.Application, index As Integer, project As WBSProject)
    '''''' Ortographe verification for the task type ''''''
    Dim correct As Boolean = True
    If (WBSDictionaryApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(index + project.ProjectConstant.WBS_START_ROW, project.ProjectConstant.WBS_COL_TYPE).value IsNot Nothing) Then If (
        Not (WBSDictionaryApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(index + project.ProjectConstant.WBS_START_ROW, project.ProjectConstant.WBS_COL_TYPE).value.Equals("Milestones"))) And
        Not (WBSDictionaryApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(index + project.ProjectConstant.WBS_START_ROW, project.ProjectConstant.WBS_COL_TYPE).value.Equals("Work")) Then correct = False

    If (Not correct) Then
        MsgBox("the type task : " + project.TasksList(index).name + " is not correctly filled")

    End If

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ProjectApp"> The MSProject application</param>
''' <param name="project"> The project where the data come</param>
''' <param name="Sequence"> The new order of the task</param>
Public Sub WBSTaskRearangement(ByRef ProjectApp As MSProject.Application, ByRef project As WBSProject, Sequence As List(Of WBSTask))
    project.SetProjectTaskList(Sequence)
    ProjectApp.ViewApplyEx(ApplyTo:=0, BuiltInView:=MSProject.PjViewType.pjViewGantt)


End Sub


''' <summary>
''' This function add sub project in master row during the creation
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ProjectApp">MS project application</param>
''' <param name="pathtoSavaProject">path where the new  project is save</param>
''' <param name="WBSProjects">The list of all projects in ram </param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function AddSubProjectIntoMaster(ByRef ProjectApp As MSProject.Application, subProjectPath As String, ByRef WBSProject As WBSProject) As Boolean
    Dim projectSource = ProjectApp.ActiveProject
    For Each project In ProjectApp.Projects
        If (project.fullname.Equals(projectSource.ResourcePoolName)) Then
            project.activate()
            ProjectApp.ViewApplyEx(ApplyTo:=0, BuiltInView:=MSProject.PjViewType.pjViewGantt)
            For Each task In ProjectApp.ActiveProject.Tasks
                Call task.OutlineHideSubtasks()
            Next
            ProjectApp.SelectRow(Row:=ProjectApp.ActiveProject.Tasks.Count + 1, RowRelative:=False)
            ProjectApp.ConsolidateProjects(Filenames:=subProjectPath + "\" + WBSProject.ProjectName + ".mpp", NewWindow:=False, HideSubtasks:=True)
            Call ProjectApp.FileSave()
            ' ProjectApp.FileCloseEx()
            projectSource.Activate()
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
''' <summary>
''' Reset all column in the wbs dictionary in grey
''' </summary>
''' <param name="WBSDictionaryApp">the wbs dictionary application </param>
''' <param name="Project">The project in WBS project</param>
Private Sub ResetAllGreyColumn(ByRef WBSDictionaryApp As Excel.Application, ByRef Project As WBSProject)
    Call ExcelReadOnlyVerification(WBSDictionaryApp)
    With WBSDictionaryApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .range(.Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.WBS_START_ROW, Project.ProjectConstant.WBS_COL_PROGRESS), .Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.WBS_START_ROW + Project.NumberOfTask, Project.ProjectConstant.WBS_COL_AC_HOURS)).Value = ""
    End With
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' This function link the master resource to the actual project
''' </summary>
''' <param name="pathToMasterProject">Path to the project master with the resources</param>
''' <param name="Projects">WBS project Class that regroup the project to export in MS project</param>
''' <param name="ProjectApp">The MS project Application</param>
Private Sub CreateResources(pathToMasterProject As String, ByRef ProjectApp As MSProject.Application)

    ProjectApp.FileOpenEx(pathToMasterProject) 'open the project master

    ProjectApp.ViewApplyEx(ApplyTo:=0, BuiltInView:=MSProject.PjViewType.pjViewGantt)
    ProjectApp.OutlineHideSubTasks()

    GlobalApplication.activateOriginalMSProject()

    ProjectApp.ResourceSharing(Share:=True, Name:=pathToMasterProject) 'link the resources

End Sub


''' <summary>
''' If an error is detected in the wbs dictionary
''' </summary>
''' <param name="WBSApp"></param>
''' <param name="errorData"></param>

Private Sub ErrorInData(ByRef WBSApp As Excel.Application, ByRef errorData As List(Of Integer()), project As WBSProject)
    WBSApp.Visible = True
    WBSApp.Worksheets.Item(1).Activate
    Dim errorInTheName As Boolean
    For Each errorD In errorData
        With WBSApp.Sheets(project.ProjectConstant.NAME_OF_WP_SHEET)
            WBSApp.Range(.Cells(errorD(1) + project.ProjectConstant.WBS_START_ROW, errorD(0)), .Cells(errorD(1) + project.ProjectConstant.WBS_START_ROW, errorD(0))).Select()
            WBSApp.Selection.Interior.color = RGB(225, 225, 0)

            If (errorD(0) = project.ProjectConstant.WBS_COL_NAME) Then
                errorInTheName = True

            End If

        End With

    Next
    If (errorInTheName) Then
        MsgBox("One or more errors were detected in the WBS dictionary " + WBSApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name + ". Please scroll the WBS dictionary " + WBSApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name + " Excel file and look for highlighted cells. In the column name you have an forbiden letter in the name of our tasks, to remind, forbiden letter are '/' '\' '*' '[' ']' '?'  Or you have a task with the same name as other task", vbCritical)
    Else
        MsgBox("One or more errors were detected in the WBS dictionary " + WBSApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name + ". Please scroll the WBS dictionary " + WBSApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name + " Excel file and look for highlighted cells ", vbCritical)
    End If
End Sub
''' <summary>
''' This function generate the indetation to create the right WBS code and organise all of this project
''' </summary>

Public Sub GenerateIndentation(ByRef Project As WBSProject, ByRef ProjectApp As MSProject.Application)

    ProjectApp.ViewApplyEx(ApplyTo:=0, BuiltInView:=MSProject.PjViewType.pjViewGantt)

    ''Create the WBS code mask on 10 level
    For i = 1 To 10

        Call ProjectApp.WBSCodeMaskEdit(Level:=i, Sequence:=0, Separator:=".")

    Next

    'Indent all the task 
    For actualRow = 1 To Project.TasksList.Count
        ProjectApp.SelectTaskField(Row:=actualRow, Column:="Name", RowRelative:=False)

        With Project.TasksList(actualRow - 1)
            If (.Level > 0) Then
                ProjectApp.OutlineIndent(.Level)
            End If
        End With

    Next

    'calc WBS in project to have correct WBS code
    Call ProjectApp.WBSCodeRenumber(All:=True)

End Sub


End Module
```

Could you please help me. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you tried [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.sort)? Have you tried the suggestions given on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69407490/vba-how-to-exchange-taskfields-rows-number-in-a-msproject-application)?

Comment: I did try the Sort function but my task list isn't classed by ID, so I am going to try to change the IDs of the task in order to use the sort Function

Comment: I tried to use what you proposed to me but I didn't achieve what I wanted to do unfortunately. so I decided to use a new list of task which I have to add into my database and then call it